Harold Grad’s derivation of Boltzmann equation
Harold Grad’s method of deriving the Boltzmann equation starts by integrating the Liouville equation:
$$\int_{D_1}\left[{\frac{\partial F_N}{\partial t} +\sum_{i=1}^{N} {\vec{v}_i}.\frac{\partial F_N}{\partial \vec{q}_i}+\sum_{i,j=1}^{N}\frac{\partial \phi_{ij}}{\partial \vec{q}_i}.\frac{\partial F_N}{\partial \vec{p}_i}}\right]d\vec{y}_2..d\vec{y}_N$$
where, $d\vec{y}_i = d\vec{v}_id\vec{q}_i$ and $D_1$ is the region of space where $|\vec{q}_i-\vec{q}_1|\geq \sigma$, and $\sigma$ is a constant, assumed to be equal to molecular diameter.
After integrating the second term, it gives the following expression:
$$\boxed{\vec{v}_1.\frac{\partial F_1^{\sigma}}{\partial \vec{q}_1}+\int_{S_2}d\vec{v}_2F_2^{\sigma}\vec{v_1}.d\vec{S}_2-\int_{S_2}d\vec{v}_2F_2^{\sigma}\vec{v_2}.d\vec{S}_2}$$
It does not match with my calculation using Gauss’s divergence theorem. Please help. My calculation is as follows:
$$\int_{D_1}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N} {\vec{v}_i}.\frac{\partial F_N}{\partial \vec{q}_i}\right]d\vec{y}_2..d\vec{y}_N$$
$${\vec{v}_1}.\frac{\partial F_1^{\sigma}}{\partial \vec{q}_1}+\int_{D_1}\left[\sum_{i=2}^{N} {\vec{v}_i}.\frac{\partial F_N}{\partial \vec{q}_i}\right]d\vec{y}_2..d\vec{y}_N$$
Using symmetry (meaning labels are not necessary), the above equation can be simplified to:
$${\vec{v}_1}.\frac{\partial F_1^{\sigma}}{\partial \vec{q}_1}+(N-1)\int_{D_1} {\vec{v}_2}.\frac{\partial F_N}{\partial \vec{q}_2}d\vec{y}_2..d\vec{y}_N$$
Now, using Gauss’s divergence theorem (converting volume integral to surface integral) on the space occupied by $d\vec{q}_2=dV_2$ where $dV_2=dq_{2x}dq_{2y}dq_{2z}$, which I got only one term which is the surface integral $\int_{S_2}d\vec{v}_2F_2^{\sigma}\vec{v_2}.d\vec{S}_2$, which makes:
$$\boxed{\vec{v}_1.\frac{\partial F_1^{\sigma}}{\partial \vec{q}_1}+\int_{S_2}d\vec{v}_2F_2^{\sigma}\vec{v_2}.d\vec{S}_2}$$
The first boxed equation is the actual derivation performed by Harold Grad(1949) taken as I studied from Stewart’s book “An Introduction to Boltzmann Equation”. But it doesn’t match with my derivation, please help, where am I wrong?
